# How should I go about estimating the time function (T(N)) for a for-loop in Java?

Tags: java

I am stumped on how to estimate the time function (T(N)) for a for-loop in Java. If I could see an example I could get the hang of it, but I cant seem to find what I am looking for. What would be the best way to estimate this?

```java
for(int x=0; x<N; x=x+2){
    for(int y=x; y<N; y++){
        System.out.println("!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about Big-O? E.g. _O(n²)_ for your code?

Answer (score 0):

First loop is executed `N/2` times, second one also `N/2` times. So totally you have `(N/2) * (N/2)` which is `O(n*n)` because constants can be safely excluded in time complexity calculation.

Comment: Second one is N/2 times (average), since the loop starts at `x`